# FlatList initialScrollIndex not working as expected

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using a horizontal FlatList as menu bar for my application. The FlatList must scroll to the clicked item and I am using initialScrollIndex for this.

But the problem is that it scrolls but the content is not visible many times.

My code

```
 <FlatList
      ref={listRef}
      data={headerMenuChannels}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: applicationTopBar.buttonBarColor,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
      }}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      horizontal={true}
      onScrollToIndexFailed={error => console.log('scroll failed', error)}
      initialScrollIndex={screenNumber}
      renderItem={v => (
        <View
          key={v.index}
          onLayout={ref => onMenuLayout(ref, v.index)}>
          <Text
            onPress={() => {
              setScreenNumber(v.index);
            }}>
            {v.item}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    />
```

Video of the problem

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkSrb.jpg)

Comment: try this listRef.current.scrollToIndex({index:0})

Comment: @ronakdholariya I have tried that but it gives the same result.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal add "removeClippedSubviews" this prop and try.

Comment: @ronakdholariya tried and still not working

Comment: can you share a video?

Comment: @ronakdholariya added this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

With `initialScrollIndex` you should use `getItemLayout` prop. Something like this:

```js
getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
  length: width,
  offset: width * index,
  index,
})}
```